# get linker error while overloading operator << for template class

Tags: c++, templates

I use visual c++.
I have a template class and I want add overlapped operation for it
I impelement it like below
in header file

```
    template <class T> class QuantityT;
    template <class T>
    inline std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream & os,const QuantityT<T> &quantity);


    template <class T>
    class QuantityT{

            T quantity_;
            template<class T> friend inline std::ostream & operator<< <T>(std::ostream & os,const QuantityT<T> &quantity);
    };
```

in souce file

```
    template <class T>
    inline std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream & os,const QuantityT<T> &quantity){
    }
```

but I get link error:

> main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class
>   std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl
>   operator<<(class std::basic_ostream > &,class QuantityT const &)"
>   (??$?6K@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABV?$QuantityT@K@@@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall
>   log::print(class std::basic_ostream
>
> > &)const " (?print@log@@UBEXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the source file's contents into the header file:

```
template <class T>
inline std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream & os,const QuantityT<T> &quantity){
}
```

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) out for more information.